# Hot to get current day from Google Calendar using php?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-calendar-api

Anyone know if this is possible?

I need to display the current day in php from my Google Calendar feed?

It would need to display this dependent on who is currently logged in to show their event.

Currently using Wordpress 3.9.2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Get started by reading the Google Calendar API here and then re-post any questions if you still have any:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Success!